# Bundler could not find gem in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, bundler

I was trying to run Middleman and am getting the following error:

```
$ middleman
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  thor (< 2.0, >= 0.15.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

So I ran `bundle install` and here's the relevant part of the output:

```
$ bundle install
Using i18n (0.6.1)
...
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle

$ middleman
...
Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
...
* i18n (0.6.1)
...

$ bundle show i18n
/Users/jh/Documents/Workspace/mywebsite-middleman/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/i18n-0.6.1
```

Does anybody know what's going on here? I keep running `bundle install` and `bundle install --deployment` like the message says and it refuses to work.

Comment: Have you tried bundle exec middleman ?

Comment: Why is that installing the gems to `vendor/bundle`?

Comment: `bundle exec middleman` gives me the same error message (but not the earlier warnings about clearing out unresolved specs).

I'm not sure why it's installing the gems to `vendor/bundle`, this is the setup that came with Middleman.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have added the middleman gem to a Gemfile and have installed using `bundle install`.

If that is the case you should run middleman as `bundle exec middleman`. This will ensure that all the other gems which have been installed as part of `bundle install` will be available to middleman.